Problema con SQL en Java
Estoy haciendo un programa en Java con el siguiente enunciado:
Actividad de clase III
Crea un programa que muestre el dni, nombre completo del alumno, junto con el número de asignaturas en las
que está matriculado. A continuación, se deberá mostrar todos los datos del alumno más joven y seguidamente los
datos del alumno más viejo.
NOTA: hacerlo con una sola sentencia SQL y utilizar los movimientos del cursor de ResultSet
El problema me está dando al salir del bucle que muestra los datos de todos los alumnos, al terminar dicho bucle me salta una excepción Operation not allowed for a result set of type ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY. y no sé a qué se debe.
Agradecería mucho la ayuda.
Aquí está la base de datos (por si sirve):
create database baseActualizada;
use baseActualizada;
-- Tabla Alumnos
CREATE TABLE alumnos (
    dni VARCHAR(9) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(50),
    apellidos VARCHAR(50),
    fechaNacimiento DATE,
    direccion VARCHAR(100),
    email VARCHAR(100)
);

-- Tabla Profesores
CREATE TABLE profesores (
    dni VARCHAR(9) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(50),
    apellido VARCHAR(50),
    especialidad VARCHAR(100)
);

-- Tabla Asignaturas
CREATE TABLE asignaturas (
    idAsignatura INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(100),
    descripcion TEXT,
    dniProfesor VARCHAR(9),
    FOREIGN KEY (dniProfesor) REFERENCES Profesores(dni)
);



-- Tabla Matriculas
CREATE TABLE matriculas (
    dniAlumno VARCHAR(9),
    idAsignatura INT,
    nota INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (dniAlumno) REFERENCES Alumnos(dni),
    FOREIGN KEY (idAsignatura) REFERENCES Asignaturas(idAsignatura),
    PRIMARY KEY (dniAlumno, idAsignatura)
);


-- Inserts para la tabla Alumnos
INSERT INTO alumnos (dni, nombre, apellidos, fechaNacimiento, direccion, email) VALUES
('12345678A', 'Juan', 'García Pérez', '1998-05-15', 'Calle Mayor 123', 'juan@gmail.com'),
('23456789B', 'María', 'Martínez López', '1999-07-20', 'Avenida Libertad 45', 'maria@hotmail.com'),
('34567890C', 'Carlos', 'Rodríguez González', '1997-12-10', 'Plaza España 8', 'carlos@yahoo.com'),
('45678901D', 'Laura', 'Fernández Sánchez', '2000-03-25', 'Calle Alameda 32', 'laura@gmail.com'),
('56789012E', 'Pablo', 'López Martín', '1996-09-05', 'Calle Real 67', 'pablo@gmail.com'),
('67890123F', 'Ana', 'Sánchez Gómez', '1999-11-18', 'Avenida Primavera 20', 'ana@hotmail.com'),
('78901234G', 'David', 'Gómez Rodríguez', '1998-08-30', 'Calle Mayor 5', 'david@yahoo.com'),
('89012345H', 'Elena', 'Pérez Fernández', '1997-04-12', 'Calle Sol 14', 'elena@gmail.com'),
('90123456I', 'Sara', 'Martín López', '1998-01-08', 'Calle Mayor 100', 'sara@hotmail.com'),
('01234567K', 'Javier', 'González Sánchez', '1995-06-22', 'Calle Real 23', 'javier@yahoo.com');

-- Inserts para la tabla Profesores
INSERT INTO profesores (dni, nombre, apellido, especialidad) VALUES
('12345678K', 'Pedro', 'Martínez', 'Matemáticas'),
('23456789L', 'Lucía', 'García', 'Física'),
('34567890M', 'Carmen', 'López', 'Historia'),
('45678901N', 'Juan', 'Sánchez', 'Biología'),
('56789012O', 'Marta', 'Rodríguez', 'Química'),
('67890123P', 'Carlos', 'Fernández', 'Literatura'),
('78901234Q', 'Elena', 'Gómez', 'Inglés'),
('89012345R', 'Pablo', 'Díaz', 'Geografía'),
('90123456S', 'Laura', 'Pérez', 'Arte'),
('01234567T', 'David', 'González', 'Educación Física');

-- Inserts para la tabla Asignaturas
INSERT INTO asignaturas (nombre, descripcion, dniProfesor) VALUES
('Matemáticas I', 'Curso introductorio de Matemáticas', '12345678K'),
('Física General', 'Conceptos básicos de Física', '23456789L'),
('Historia del Mundo Contemporáneo', 'Panorama histórico del siglo XX', '34567890M'),
('Biología Celular', 'Estudio de la célula y sus funciones', '45678901N'),
('Química Orgánica', 'Química de los compuestos orgánicos', '56789012O'),
('Literatura Española', 'Análisis de la literatura española', '67890123P'),
('Inglés Avanzado', 'Curso de inglés para nivel avanzado', '78901234Q'),
('Geografía Humana', 'Estudio de la relación entre la sociedad y el medio ambiente', '89012345R'),
('Arte Renacentista', 'Estudio del arte durante el Renacimiento', '90123456S'),
('Educación Física', 'Actividades deportivas y recreativas', '01234567T');

-- Inserts para la tabla Matriculas
INSERT INTO matriculas (dniAlumno, idAsignatura, nota) VALUES
('12345678A', 1, 2), 
('12345678A', 3, 3), 
('23456789B', 2, 7), 
('34567890C', 3, 6), 
('45678901D', 4, 5), 
('56789012E', 5, 9), 
('67890123F', 6, 10), 
('78901234G', 7, 2), 
('89012345H', 8, 2), 
('90123456I', 9, 3), 
('01234567K', 10, 1),
('56789012E', 3, 8), 
('90123456I', 4, 6),
('12345678A', 5, 7), 
('12345678A', 6, 7), 
('23456789B', 7, 4), 
('34567890C', 8, 3), 
('45678901D', 9, 5), 
('56789012E', 10, 7), 
('67890123F', 7, 10), 
('78901234G', 8, 8), 
('89012345H', 2, 7), 
('90123456I', 10, 4), 
('01234567K', 9, 5); 

Este es el código del programa:
        //importar todo lo de sql
        import java.sql.*;

        public class Datos {
       /**
        * método principal
        */
       public static void main(String[] args) {
        //datos de conexión a la base de datos
        String baseDatos = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/baseActualizada";
        String usuario = "root";
        String claveAcceso = "franceselquemehackee";

        //intentar la conexión
        try {
            Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(baseDatos, usuario, claveAcceso);
            System.out.print("Conexión realizada.");

            //consulta SQL
            String consultaSql = "select alu.dni, concat(alu.nombre, \" \", alu.apellidos) as nombre_completo, count(asi.nombre) as numero_asignaturas  from alumnos as alu inner join matriculas as ma on alu.dni = ma.dniAlumno inner join asignaturas as asi on ma.idAsignatura = asi.idAsignatura group by alu.dni order by alu.fechaNacimiento desc;";

            //cosas del sql
            Statement sentencia = conexion.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = sentencia.executeQuery(consultaSql);

            //mostrar los datos generales
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("-------------------------------");
                System.out.println("DNI: " + rs.getString("alu.dni"));
                System.out.println("Nombre completo: " + rs.getString("nombre_completo"));
                System.out.println("Número de asignaturas: " + rs.getInt("numero_asignaturas"));
            }

            //mpver el cursor al final para obtener los datos del alumno más viejo
            if (rs.last()) {
                String dniViejo = rs.getString("alu.dni");
                String nombreCompletoViejo = rs.getString("nombre_completo");
                int numeroAsignaturasViejo = rs.getInt("numero_asignaturas");

                System.out.println("Datos del alumno más viejo: ");
                System.out.println("Nombre: " + nombreCompletoViejo + " DNI: " + dniViejo + " Número de asignaturas: " + numeroAsignaturasViejo);
            }

            //mpver el cursor al principio para obtener los datos del alumno más joven
            if (rs.first()) {
                String dniJoven = rs.getString("alu.dni");
                String nombreCompletoJoven = rs.getString("nombre_completo");
                int numeroAsignaturasJoven = rs.getInt("numero_asignaturas");

                System.out.println("Datos del alumno más viejo: ");
                System.out.println("Nombre: " + nombreCompletoJoven + " DNI: " + dniJoven + " Número de asignaturas: " + numeroAsignaturasJoven);
            }
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error conectando a la base de datos: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


Eso que estaas haciendo para ver el alumno más joven y más viejo lo puedes hacer en el bucle sobre el que iteras controlando la primera iteración y la última. Así no tienes que mover el cursor y así no te dará ese error que te indica que el cursor solo puede moverse hacia adelante, no hacia atrás.

Para saber si estás en la primera iteración puedes tener un flag "primero" inicializado a true, y cuando acabas la primera iteración lo pones a false. Para el último elemento como no sabes cual va a ser, puedes guardar los datos a cada iteración en unas variables e ir machacándolas, al salir del bucle los datos que queden en esas variables serán del último elemento.

Define tu ResultSet como https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE

El mensaje de error indica el problema:

Operation not allowed for a result set of type
ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY

De forma predeterminada los ResultSet obtenidos en las consultas son de tipo ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, lo que indica que el ResultSet solo puede "avanzar" de registro en registro, pero no puede moverse a un registro puntual como por ejemplo el último (rs.last()).
En tu caso, necesitas crear un objeto ResultSet Scrollable, por lo que debes realizar el siguiente cambio usando TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE:
//Statement sentencia = conexion.createStatement();
Statement sentencia = conexion.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet rs = sentencia.executeQuery(consultaSql);


muchas gracias!
